# Ubuntu is relatively unstable

Tags: 14.04, freeze, crash

Ubuntu is much less stable than the dominant OS. It is mostly but not solely Firefox when opening pages like Issuu or html5 sites, where my system hangs. I had not expected to find my computer hanging so often when I installed it. My question is, has Ubuntu always been unstable? How often does an average user experience their system to hang, completely unable to get anything out of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+{<kbd>Backspace</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>T</kbd>} ?

My video driver is `u@laptop:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: 
  Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
  Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0573 
  Kernel driver in use: i915
```

As another example, after restarting, the 'error report' itself got a frozen UI when I expanded the disassembly bullet. This didn't freeze the OS luckily.

[image: nonresponsive]

Another source of OS freezes is when I connect my iPhone. There are two or three black phone icons popping up on the task bar (apparently it connects twice automatically). If I don't press cancel on both, the OS will hang. When I leave one of the tow pop ups and return to it later (simply mouse over the task bar) the OS will freeze. This is pretty dramatic. I would almost think that some MS saboteurs have joined the Ubuntu development team.

Here is some of the syslog of a crash. I am not logging memory usage. Maybe it helps? Is this question closed and can no one answer anymore? I think the \00's at the end are my hard reset of the computer. Or are they?

```
Dec  3 21:13:06 laptop dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.178.21 on wlan0 to 192.168.178.1 port 67 (xid=0x631ce484)
Dec  3 21:13:07 laptop dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.178.21 from 192.168.178.1
Dec  3 21:13:07 laptop dhclient: bound to 192.168.178.21 -- renewal in 1488 seconds.
Dec  3 21:13:07 laptop NetworkManager[1172]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed renew -> renew
Dec  3 21:13:07 laptop NetworkManager[1172]: <info>   address 192.168.178.21
Dec  3 21:13:07 laptop NetworkManager[1172]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Dec  3 21:13:07 laptop NetworkManager[1172]: <info>   gateway 192.168.178.1
Dec  3 21:13:07 laptop NetworkManager[1172]: <info>   nameserver '84.116.46.23'
Dec  3 21:13:07 laptop NetworkManager[1172]: <info>   nameserver '84.116.46.22'
Dec  3 21:13:07 laptop NetworkManager[1172]: <info>   domain name 'dynamic.ziggo.nl'
Dec  3 21:13:07 laptop dbus[1018]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Dec  3 21:13:07 laptop dbus[1018]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec  3 21:14:29 laptop kernel: [12582.263983] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:60:67:20:5b:71:1c:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.15 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=11661 PROTO=2 
Dec  3 21:15:01 laptop CRON[8241]: (www-data) CMD (php --define suhosin.memory_limit=512M /usr/share/cacti/site/poller.php 2>&1 >/dev/null | if [ -f /usr/bin/ts ] ; then ts ; else tee ; fi >> /var/log/cacti/poller-error.log)
Dec  3 21:16:36 laptop kernel: [12709.383492] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b0:34:95:bb:d5:2a:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.10 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=45428 PROTO=2 
Dec  3 21:17:01 laptop CRON[8248]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec  3 21:19:36 laptop kernel: [12888.997931] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:44:d8:84:12:bb:d9:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.11 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=31002 PROTO=2 
Dec  3 21:20:01 laptop CRON[8254]: (www-data) CMD (php --define suhosin.memory_limit=512M /usr/share/cacti/site/poller.php 2>&1 >/dev/null | if [ -f /usr/bin/ts ] ; then ts ; else tee ; fi >> /var/log/cacti/poller-error.log)
Dec  3 21:24:59 laptop kernel: [13212.949348] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:60:67:20:5b:71:1c:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.15 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=11686 PROTO=2 
Dec  3 21:25:01 laptop CRON[8264]: (www-data) CMD (php --define suhosin.memory_limit=512M /usr/share/cacti/site/poller.php 2>&1 >/dev/null | if [ -f /usr/bin/ts ] ; then ts ; else tee ; fi >> /var/log/cacti/poller-error.log)
Dec  3 21:29:11 laptop kernel: [13465.245956] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:60:67:20:5b:71:1c:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.15 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=11693 PROTO=2 
Dec  3 21:30:01 laptop CRON[8279]: (www-data) CMD (php --define suhosin.memory_limit=512M /usr/share/cacti/site/poller.php 2>&1 >/dev/null | if [ -f /usr/bin/ts ] ; then ts ; else tee ; fi >> /var/log/cacti/poller-error.log)
Dec  3 21:31:17 laptop kernel: [13591.032684] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:90:6e:bb:c1:52:ab:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Dec  3 21:33:24 laptop kernel: [13717.949294] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b0:34:95:bb:d5:2a:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.10 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=47266 PROTO=2 
Dec  3 21:35:01 laptop CRON[8286]: (www-data) CMD (php --define suhosin.memory_limit=512M /usr/share/cacti/site/poller.php 2>&1 >/dev/null | if [ -f /usr/bin/ts ] ; then ts ; else tee ; fi >> /var/log/cacti/poller-error.log)
Dec  3 21:35:29 laptop kernel: [13843.329068] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:90:6e:bb:c1:52:ab:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
:
:
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
Dec  3 21:47:10 laptop rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="1190" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

Comment: You probably did not install video drivers. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: My experience, until I jumped ship for Debian (and even today on some Ubuntu machines I manage), was quite the contrary: I found Ubuntu to be far *more* stable than the dominant OS. Clearly, as always, YMMV

Comment: I have been deploying Ubuntu since last ten years from university where I teach to schools, corporate environment, labs and many other places, no issues of any stability. In fact its the most polished current LTS around. You definitely have some installation issues. Download latest 14.04.3 and do a fresh clean install and then see if issue persists. You are using Intel graphics so no secondary drivers for it needed.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @guntbert, since it is the single OS on this single PC, maybe there is a mysterious connection between the different sources of freezes that will become apparent in due time.

Comment: @guntbert can you reopen the question?